# retrieving integer value from the UITextField into a NSInteger variable

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitextfield, nsinteger

```
UITextField *textField;
NSInteger intRollNumber;
```

I want to take `rollNumber` as input from the `textField` and store the value into `intRollNumber` .

How i do that? Because I am unable to convert the string into integer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Like this?

```
NSString *str = [textField text]
int RollNumber = [str intValue];
```

Answer (score 2):

See the [text property](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006888-CH3-SW2) and [integerValue](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/integerValue).