# iOS - How can I get an integer from a text area?

Tags: ios, textbox, textarea

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [retrieving integer value from the UITextField into a NSInteger variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886925/retrieving-integer-value-from-the-uitextfield-into-a-nsinteger-variable)

I have users fill in a text box with a number. I want to use this number in a calculation; how can i put it in a variable? So far I only have:

```
NSInteger *answer = results........
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `intValue` or `integerValue` from the [`NSString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) class.

```
int answer = [myTextField.text intValue];
```

or

```
NSInteger answer = [myTextField.text integerValue];
```

You can also use `floatValue` and `doubleValue` for floating-point inputs.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSInteger answer = [textField.text integerValue];
```

OR

```
int answer = [textField.text intValue];
```

Comment: NSInteger is not a class; no "*" needed, and I don't think "int" is a method on NSString.

Comment: Check http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html for intValue.
Returns the integer value of the receiver’s text.

- (int)intValue

Comment: "intValue" is a method on NSString; "int", which is what your answer says, is not.

Comment: aha, yes well spotted :)