# how to convert uitextfield integer into string

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to iOS. I need to convert textfield integer value into string. I created textfield name as `value1` and string as `str1`.

```
str1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", value1];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [retrieving integer value from the UITextField into a NSInteger variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886925/retrieving-integer-value-from-the-uitextfield-into-a-nsinteger-variable)

Answer (score 2):

By default, `UITextField` returns a `NSString` value.

> So you can get any value like this :

```
NSString *str1 = value1.text;
```

> As simple as that, but if you want to convert it to `Int` then,

```
int strInt = str1.intValue;
NSInteger strInteger = str1.integerValue;
```

> If want to converts to a `Double` value,

```
double strDouble = str1.doubleValue;
CGFloat strCGFloat = str1.doubleValue;
```

> And yes, if you don't need to perform anything on `str1` then you shouldn't need to create an instance, you can directly convert it like this.

```
int strInt = value1.text.intValue;
NSInteger strInteger = value1.text.intValue;
```

Comment: while passing that sring as parameter means its storing different value @Hemang